# Storing and Restoring Variations in a Long

Tags: c#, .net, math, logic

I have n-values within the same fix minimum and maximum range.

```
// value range
int minValue = 0;
int maxValue = 100;
int valueCount = 3; // number of values

// Example 1
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;

// Example 2
int a = 100;
int b = 100;
int c = 100;

// Example 3
int a = 12;
int b = 80;
int c = 27;
```

Example 1 and 2 showing the minimum and maximum variation of these 3 values, where Example 3 shows some random values.

The possible number of all variations for these 3 values with the given minimum and maximum value is 100 * 100 * 100 = 1.000.000.

So if i define that 0 stands for the variation of Example 1 and that 1.000.000 stands for the variation of example 2. How do i calculate a value that stands for Example 3?

Or better, how do i loop thru all possible variations and how to restore them.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
{
    int[] values = GetValues(i, minValue, maxValue, valueCount);
}
```

So what i'm looking for is something that works like the GetValues() methode above.

Comment: There are 1030301 possible variation; 101 * 101 * 101

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, assuming that your approach is a good one.  It is not.  Research your problem before committing to a solution, google "c# generate all combinations" first.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, that's what i've tried for hours. But you are right: "if you ask the wrong question you won't get the correct answer." Finally i had no luck with my google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just like finding the indexes for a n-dimensional array when you know the offset of memory for that cell.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetValues(long i, int minValue, int maxValue, int valueCount)
{
    var range = maxValue - minValue + 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < valueCount; j++)
    {
        yield return (int)(i % range + minValue);
        i = i / range;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in the comment the example you provided is wrong.

There are **1030301** number of variation, because each item can have **101** different value (from 0 to 100) and total number of variations is `101*101*101 = 11030301`.

Comment: I do not understand the `i=i-1` part. If i=0, values 0, 0 and 0 should come out. In your example, this does not happen.

Comment: `GetValues(1,0,100,3)` should return `{0,0,0}` not `{0,0,1}` @MartinMulder

Comment: @dotctor: Where is that 1 coming from? The OP also starts with 0, not 1. And the number 0 should return {0,0,0}.

Answer (score 1):

You have to multiply with `101`, not `100` since your range (from 0 to 100) contains 101 nummbers. Ranges 1 to 100 or 0 to 99 contain 100 numbers.

So your maximum value is not `1000000` but `1030301`.

To store your value in a `long` (which in your example could also be an `int`):

```
long stored = c * 101 * 101 + b * 101 + a;
```

To restored it:

```
int restoredA = stored % 101;
int restoredB = stored / 101 % 101;
int restoredC = stored / 101 / 101;
```

In case of your function:

```
int[] GetValues(long stored, int minValue, int maxValue, int valueCount);
{
    // TODO: Do some parameter checking.
    int[] results = new int[valueCount];
    int rangeSize = maxValue - minValue + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < valueCount; i++)
    {
        results[i] = rangeSize % diff + minValue;
        stored = stored / diff; 
    }
    return results;
}
```

Of course when to much values are stored into that `long`, or the range beteen `minValue` and `maxValue` is to large, they do not fit.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the vote was placed when you were using 100 instead of 101 as the multiplier, so maybe that's the reason?

Comment: @Joe Farell: That is correct. IMO a comment should have worked better so people can get the change to improve their question or answer. This way the downvoter will never get a reply from me that it is fixed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the familiar base-10 number system as a simple example of what you're trying to do. Suppose you want to store three values that are somewhere in the range of [0, 9] as a single number—for instance, 2, 5, and 7. You'd simply write it as the number 257, which represents a sum of multiples of successive powers of ten, because ten is the number of unique values that each digit can have.

257 = 2 * 10<sup>2</sup> + 5 * 10<sup>1</sup> + 7 * 10<sup>0</sup>

In the same way, you can pack values together for any base other than 10. In the example you give, the allowable range for each number is [0, 100], which contains 101 distinct integers, so you'd construct your packed value as a sum of multiples of successive powers of 101, like so:

x = a * 101<sup>2</sup> + b * 101<sup>1</sup> + c * 101<sup>0</sup>

From here, you should be able to extrapolate to the generic case where you have the range [`minValue`, `maxValue`], where each component has `maxValue - minValue + 1` possible values, but let me know if you need more detail.